# SQLAlchemy session is not adding some of my objects

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy

I created some mapped objects using the declarative style in SQLAlchemy. I have a mapping called ThermafuserReading which has a composed primary key made up of the Time_stamp column which is DateTime and ThermafuserId column which is an Integer and also acts as a Foreign Key to another table called Thermafuser. This is the definition of the class

```
class ThermafuserReading(Base):
"""Class to map to the Thermafuser Readings table in the HVAC DB"""

__tablename__ = 'Thermafuser_Reading'

_timestamp = Column('Time_stamp', DateTime, primary_key = True)
_thermafuserId = Column('ThermafuserId', Integer, ForeignKey("Thermafuser.ThermafuserId"), primary_key = True)
_roomOccupied = Column('RoomOccupied', Boolean)
_zoneTemperature = Column('ZoneTemperature', Float)
_supplyAir = Column('SupplyAir', Float, nullable=True)
_airflowFeedback = Column('AirflowFeedback', Float, nullable=True)
_CO2Input = Column('CO2Input', Float, nullable=True)
_maxAirflow = Column('MaxAirflow', Float, nullable=True)
_minAirflow = Column('MinAirflow', Float, nullable=True)
_unoccupiedHeatingSetpoint = Column('UnoccupiedHeatingSetpoint', Float, nullable=True)
_unoccupiedCoolingSetpoint = Column('UnoccupiedCoolingSetpoint', Float, nullable=True)
_occupiedCoolingSetpoint = Column('OccupiedCoolingSetpoint', Float, nullable=True)
_occupiedHeatingSetpoint = Column('OccupiedHeatingSetpoint', Float, nullable=True)
_terminalLoad = Column('TerminalLoad', Float, nullable=True)

#Relationship between Thermafuser Reading and Thermafuser
_thermafuser = relationship("Thermafuser", back_populates = "_thermafuserReadings",  cascade = "all, delete-orphan", single_parent = True)
```

I am creating a session in the following way

```
sqlengine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://user:password@localhost:3306/HVAC")
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=sqlengine)
    session = Session()
```

At some point in my code I am creating a list called readings of Thermafuser Readings and adding such list the session via session.add_all(readings)

This are some example elements printed from the list readings:

```
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2016-12-31 23:30:00')>
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2016-12-31 23:35:00')>
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2016-12-31 23:40:00')>
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2016-12-31 23:45:00')>
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2016-12-31 23:50:00')>
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2016-12-31 23:55:00')>
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-01 00:00:00')>
```

The problem is that the session is only keeping the last item in this list, eventhough I did session.add_all(readings) e.g. This is what the session has inside:

```
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-01 00:00:00')>
```

I know the session keeps track of objects which have the same primary key and thus inserts only one instance of such objects in the sesssion but in this case the primary key (thermafuserId, timestamp) is different at each instance. I dont know why the session is only adding the last element of my list while neglecting the other elements.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I kept doing some tests and found out the reason why only the last element of the list is being added to the session. The problem lies in the identity_key for each of the objects in my list *readings*. This is the code I used for my tests:

```
for reading in readings:
    print(reading, mapper.identity_key_from_instance(reading))
```

and this are some of the results

```
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:15:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:20:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:25:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:30:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:35:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:40:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:45:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:50:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-14 23:55:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
<ThermafuserReading(thermafuserId = '21', timestamp = '2017-01-15 00:00:00')> (<class 'hvacDBMapping.ThermafuserReading'>, (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 0, 0), 21))
```

As you can observe, the function sqlalchemy.orm.util.identity_key_from_instance() is not creating the identity keys correctly for my datetime objects.

Can somebody help me clarify why?

**EDIT**

This is a simplified code that illustrates the problem. No connection to the database in this code. The code where this problem first appeared is much more involved and posting it will only create confusion, but this code reproduces the error.

```
Session = sessionmaker()
session = Session() 

mapper = inspect(ThermafuserReading)

#Open the csv file
csvFilePath = "/Users/davidlaredorazo/Box Sync/Data/Zone4/1C1A/1C1A 2016-12-31.csv"
with open(csvFilePath, 'r') as csvfile:

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    componentId = 1
    count = 0

    reading = ThermafuserReading(None, componentId)

    for row in reader:

        if count == 0:
            count += 1
            continue

        #print(row)
        timestamp = parse(row[0], None, ignoretz = True)

        reading.timestamp = timestamp
        new_object = copy.copy(reading)
        new_object.timestamp = timestamp

        print(new_object, mapper.identity_key_from_instance(new_object))
        session.add(new_object)

print("new elements")
for new in session.new:
    print(new, mapper.identity_key_from_instance(new_object))
```

Comment: You need to post the code where you create these instances. (Are you sure you aren't just creating one instance and adding the same instance to the list?) As well as how you're printing these instances. (For all we know you're printing `timestamp = <completely different field than self._timestamp>`.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just posted a code snippet that reproduces the error. I am sure that I am not creating just one instance as i am copying the instance using copy.copy.

Comment: Well, that's your problem. You're messing with SQLAlchemy internals by using `copy`. Don't do that. If you really want to, you need to exclude `_sa_instance_state` from being copied.

Comment: So what would be the right approach to insert an object in the session. The thing is that I create a single instance of the object i want to insert, then I modify its attributes and copy that instance and the insert it in the session. What would be the correct approach then? thanks for your comment

Comment: Don't use `copy`. Manually create `ThermafuserReading` instances and copy the attributes yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As univerio mentioned in the comments. What I was doing wrong was using copy.copy to copy instances of my mapped objects, this was messing with _sa_instance_state. The solution was to create an "ad hoc" copy function for my instances. Here is the copy function I used, this, indeed solved the problem.

```
def copy_sqla_object(obj, omit_fk=True):
    """Given an SQLAlchemy object, creates a new object (FOR WHICH THE OBJECT
    MUST SUPPORT CREATION USING __init__() WITH NO PARAMETERS), and copies
    across all attributes, omitting PKs, FKs (by default), and relationship
    attributes."""
    cls = type(obj)
    mapper = class_mapper(cls)
    newobj = cls()  # not: cls.__new__(cls)
    pk_keys = set([c.key for c in mapper.primary_key])
    rel_keys = set([c.key for c in mapper.relationships])
    prohibited = pk_keys | rel_keys
    if omit_fk:
        fk_keys = set([c.key for c in mapper.columns if c.foreign_keys])
        prohibited = prohibited | fk_keys
    for k in [p.key for p in mapper.iterate_properties if p.key not in prohibited]:
        try:
            value = getattr(obj, k)
            setattr(newobj, k, value)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    return newobj
```

You can see a more detailed discussion of this issue in

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/HVSxndh23m0